# Convert Dolby Vision file in MKV container to MP4 container

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, mp4, matroska

I have a 5GB Dolby Vision file encoded in MKV container. If I play this file in my LG CX TV, there is a discoloration all over the display. Apparently the default WebOS media player that comes with the LG OLED TV cannot decode DV with MKV container properly. I am trying to convert the DV with MKV container to DV MP4. Its the first time I am using FFMpeg to convert. I ran the command `ffmpeg -i Tiny.mkv Tiny_converted.mp4` in the command prompt. It started running and threw a lot of "Skipping NAL ******" (screenshot attached). I am not sure if these are warning or error messages. Any way I left it running for around 4 hours and then I stopped it. I wasn't sure if it was actually converting it.

1. Is it the right command to simply convert a DV MKV to DV MP4 without losing DV and Dolby audio?
2. Are those warning messages or error messages?
3. How long does it normally take to convert a 5GB file?

Are these "Skipping NAL unit 62" error messages?

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhL2a.png)

Regards,
Anish

Comment: I have no clue what parameters you need to set in ffmpeg to do this - I just use an idiot-proof front end for it on Mac, [Smart Converter](https://shedworx.com/smart-converter/) [there are free & paid versions, I use the free one]. I'm sure you could find something similar for any platform. Drop a file, tell it what you want it to make & for what device. Press 'Go'. Listen to your computer's fans ramp up to top speed for the next several hours. I'm currently transcoding a 4-hour 8GB movie mkv to mp4, it's doing about 1% per minute on a 12-core dual Xeon. Expect a laptop to take a *lot* longer.

Comment: I don't know Smart Converter but seems similar to Handbrake, free and open-source. Works great but the same caveats apply.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - I don't know the actual practical differences between ffmpeg & Handbrake, but I think they share some components. I just use this particular app because it does all the hard work pushing the commands to ffmpeg, meaning I don't need to have any clue how to actually make ffmpeg work. That suits me just fine;))

Comment: @Tetsujin Handbrake is just a front-end with a huge list of presets for pretty much any conversion I can think of.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Possibly there is an open issue. See this: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5688